# Cell label Does not catching value in table view

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have two arrays of number which i'm trying to match and then want to change background of cell label in cellForRowAtIndexPath delegate in `TableView`. But it is not catching my condition even when the condition meets correctly. This is my code:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
if dataLoded {
        if isGroupListView {

            if localGroupChannelsArr.count > 0 {
                noDataFoundView.isHidden = true
            }else {
                noDataFoundView.isHidden = false
            }

            return localGroupChannelsArr.count
        }

        if localSingleChannelsArr.count > 0 {
            noDataFoundView.isHidden = true
        }else {
            noDataFoundView.isHidden = false
        }

        return localSingleChannelsArr.count
    }
}
 func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
 var cell = ChatRoomCellView()

    var channelRoom = ChatRoom()
   // var onlineStatus = OnlineUser()

    if isGroupListView {
        channelRoom = localGroupChannelsArr[indexPath.row]
        cell = groupChatRoomsList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "GroupRoomCellView") as! ChatRoomCellView
    }else {
        channelRoom = localSingleChannelsArr[indexPath.row]
        cell = singleChatRoomsList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SingleRoomCellView") as! ChatRoomCellView

        for (phone, number) in zip(numbers, onlineUserArray) {

            print(phone)
            print(phone,number.phone!)
                if phone == number.phone
                {
                    if number.status == "online"
                    {
                        print("Matched")
                        cell.onlineStatusLbl.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08950354904, green: 0.807744801, blue: 0.07534810156, alpha: 1)
                    }
                    else if number.status == "offline"
                    {
                        cell.onlineStatusLbl.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        cell.onlineStatusLbl.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
                    }
                }
            }
    }

    cell.selectionStyle = .none
    cell.delegate = self
    cell.myIndexPath = indexPath
    cell.chatRoomObj = channelRoom
    cell.onlineUser = onlineUserArray
    cell.configCell()

    return cell
}
```

Now when it meets the condition, `if phone == number.phone`
It does not change color for the cell label

Comment: Have you set a breakpoint to determine that it actually sets the backgroundColor? What happens in cell.configCell()? Is it possible it resets the background color somehwere?

Comment: Yeah i have set breakpoints also. it stop at breakpoint but color does not change. In configCell() i set other values for the cell labels and images. @andlin

Comment: What does configCell() do?

Comment: @JunaidKhan - you say *"it is not catching my condition even when the condition meet correctly"* ... do you mean you *believe* `phone == number.phone`, but it's not dropping into the `number.status` ifs? Or do you mean, you've set a breakpoint and stepped through and the appropriate `cell.onlineStatusLbl.backgroundColor = ...` line ***is*** being executed, but the background color is not changing?

Comment: both condition if phone == number.phone and number.status == "online" works fine but the color of label does not change. @DonMag

Comment: @JunaidKhan - have you double-checked your `cell.configCell()` func to make sure it's not setting the label's background color?

Comment: yes i have checked that. @DonMag

Comment: @JunaidKhan - hmmm... is it possible your for loop ends up finding `phone == number.phone` more than once, always with the same `number.status` result?

Comment: yes , its matched with number multiple times. @DonMag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is that you are looping through the ***entire array*** every time you get a request for a cell. What you probably want to do is get the `number` for the `indexPath.row` and loop through the `onlineUserArray` to find the status.

Something like this (I don't know your exact data structure, but this should be along the right lines):

```
    // inside cellForRowAt

    cell = singleChatRoomsList.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "SingleRoomCellView") as! ChatRoomCellView

    // just to make it easy to see what's going on in the debug console
    print(indexPath)

    let phone = numbers[indexPath.row]

    for number in onlineUserArray
    {
        print(number)
        if number.phone == phone
        {
            if number.status == 1
            {
                print("Matched")
                cell.theLabel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.08950354904, green: 0.807744801, blue: 0.07534810156, alpha: 1)
            }
            else if number.status == 0
            {
                cell.theLabel.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.6666666865, green: 0.6666666865, blue: 0.6666666865, alpha: 1)
            }
            else
            {
                cell.theLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
            }
            print("found a match, so break out of the loop")
            break
        }
    }
```

Comment: I think you might be right but i have sort it out myself. @DonMag